# submit() in Form Elements

Tags: javascript

I noticed that you can call `submit()` in event handlers of form elements. For example,

```
<input id="myInput" type="button" onclick="submit()" value="Test" />
```

clicking the button generated by the code above will submit the form. The funny thing is, I can't call `submit()` outside the event handler. There is no `submit` member defined for the input element.(`document.getElementById("myInput").submit` is `undefined`.) So, where is this function defined, and where can I find a reference to this function?

Comment: For anyone who (like me) thinks it shouldn't work: http://jsbin.com/ozodi4

Comment: This horror is just another reason never to use inline event handler attributes.

Comment: @bobince What's the best alternative? You mean something like this? 'document.getElementById("myInput").onclick = function foo() {}'

Comment: Yes. Or addEventListener/attachEvent/your-favoured-library's-event-binding-function if you need multiple handlers per element. (Although either way, you wouldn't want to use a named function expression there due to IE<9 JScript bugs; just `function() {...}` would do it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is described [here in section 19.1.6](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_01.htm):

> Event handlers defined as HTML attributes have a more complex scope chain (...)

and

> The scope chain of an event handler does not stop with the object that defines the handler: it proceeds up the containment hierarchy. For the `onclick` event handler described earlier, the scope chain begins with the call object of the handler function. Then it proceeds to the Button object, as we've discussed. After that, it continues up the HTML element containment hierarchy and includes, at a minimum, the HTML `<form>` element that contains the button and the `Document` object that contains the form. The precise composition of the scope chain has never been standardized and is implementation-dependent. Netscape 6 and Mozilla include all containing objects (even things such as `<div>` tags), while IE 6 sticks to a more minimal set that includes the target element, plus the containing Form object (if any) and the Document object. Regardless of the browser, the final object in the scope chain is the Window object, as it always is in client-side JavaScript.

So I guess it was already clear that the `submit` function is the one of the `form`. And if the event handler is defined via an HTML attribute, then the scope chain are the element itself and its parents. **But** it is not standardized, so one should not rely on that behavior.

Comment: Wow. The relevant bit being *"Furthermore, since there is no standard for the precise composition of the scope chain of an event handler, it is safest to assume that it contains only the target element and the global Window object."*. Or just use DOM2 handlers and traversal instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice you get the same error with the following:

```
<input id="myInput" type="button" onclick="this.submit()" value="Test" />
```

That is, submit() is not a method of the HTMLInputElement, but submit() is resolving to the Form's submit() function.

For example:

```
<form action='test.php' method='get' id='myForm'>
   <input id="myInput" type="button" onclick="Foo()" value="Test" />
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('myForm').Foo = function() {
   alert('Bar!');
};
</script>
```

Clicking the button alerts 'Bar!'.

Comment: Yes, but **why**? What specifies this behavior? It's like a massive `with` clause or something.

Comment: ... good question. I can't find anything in the spec, so as Felix's answer implies, it's implementation specific. Scary thought. I guess the take home message is to define the scope with 'this' to be sure of cross browser compatibility.